# How to find last column of a table using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I have a table like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table2">
    <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Age
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mario
        </td>
        <th>Age: 78
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane
        </td>
        <td>Age: 67
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>James
        </td>
        <th>Age: 92
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the last `td` from all rows using Html Agility Pack.
Here is my C# code so far:

```
await page.GoToAsync(NumOfSaleItems, new NavigationOptions
{
    WaitUntil = new WaitUntilNavigation[] { WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded }
});
var html4 = page.GetContentAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var htmlDoc4 = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc4.LoadHtml(html4);
var SelectTable = htmlDoc4.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]");
if (SelectTable.Count == 0)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    foreach (HtmlNode row in SelectTable)//
    {
        string value = row.InnerText;
        value = value.ToString();
        var firstSpaceIndex = value.IndexOf(" ");
        var firstString = value.Substring(0, firstSpaceIndex);
        LastSellingDates.Add(firstString);
    }                                            
}
```

How can I get only the last column of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `XPath` you want is: `//table[@id='table2']//tr/td[last()]`.

`//table[@id='table2']` finds the table by ID anywhere in the document.  This is preferable to a long brittle path from the root, since a table ID is less likely to change than the rest of the HTML structure.

`//tr` gets the descendent rows in the table.  I'm using two slashes in case there might be an intervening `<tbody>` element in the actual HTML.

`/td[last()]` gets the last `<td>` in each row.

From there you just need to select the `InnerText` of each `<td>`.

```
var tds = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr/td[last()]");
var values = tds?.Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList() ?? new List<string>();
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7I8yk1